# Google Maps API not working with an apostrophe?

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to use the Google Maps API to get the latitude and longitude of a few locations. For some reason, whenever I send a place name with an apostrophe, it does not return any results.

For instance, if I send the following requests for searching **Berri's Pizza Cafe** I get the results mentioned below

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=berri%27s+pizza+cafe&sensor=false
{"results" : [],    "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"}
```

And this

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Berri%27s%20Pizza%20Cafe&output=json
{
  "name": "Berri's Pizza Cafe",
  "Status": {
    "code": 602,
    "request": "geocode"
  }
}
```

I assume this is a problem with Google Maps API (found a forum post saying this was an issue in the javascript API but was supposedly fixed there, probably not in this)

Does anyone have a workaround for this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are attempting to geocode a business name; the geocoder works with postal addresses. Omitting the apostrophe doesn't get any results either (thus proving it's not the apostrophe which is the problem).

Note that the Maps geocoder is far more sophisticated and uses a variety of data sources to locate targets, including address geolocation and business name lookup.

You may be able to find the data you're looking for using the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/) (but you will need to specify the city which you are currently omitting).

Comment: Thanks that seems to be the problem.